# Squid stop working,constantly freezes

Tags: linux, ubuntu, proxy, squid

I'm running Squid v. 3.3.11. I have around 150 active users. The machine physical resources are more than the recommended. I don't use the cache function, so it is turned off.

The problem is when I turn on the proxy after some days of work, it just freezes, I mean the client cant resolve any websites and I noticed little before the internet become very laggy before it crashes total and stop resolve websites. If I restart the service or the server the problem is solved for an, may be 10 minutes, then it just stops again. There is nothing in the cache.log .I've noticed that when it stops when I open `/var/log/squid/access.log` it writes in the log. Here is a part from the log file.

```
10.62.8.109 - - [19/Jan/2016:14:24:32 +0200] 200 0 TCP_MISS:HIER_DIRECT "CONNECT pollserver.lastpass.com:443 HTTP/1.1"
10.62.8.109 - - [19/Jan/2016:14:24:32 +0200] 200 0 TCP_MISS:HIER_DIRECT "CONNECT mtalk.google.com:443 HTTP/1.1"
10.62.8.109 - - [19/Jan/2016:14:25:06 +0200] 407 0 TCP_DENIED_ABORTED:HIER_NONE "GET http://www.data.bg/ HTTP/1.1"
10.62.8.109 - - [19/Jan/2016:14:25:06 +0200] 200 5239 TCP_MISS:HIER_DIRECT "CONNECT play.google.com:443 HTTP/1.1"
10.62.8.109 - - [19/Jan/2016:14:25:06 +0200] 200 1741 TCP_MISS:HIER_DIRECT "CONNECT plus.google.com:443 HTTP/1.1"
10.62.8.109 - - [19/Jan/2016:14:25:06 +0200] 200 5011 TCP_MISS:HIER_DIRECT "CONNECT play.google.com:443 HTTP/1.1"
10.62.8.109 - - [19/Jan/2016:14:25:16 +0200] 200 189800 TCP_MISS:HIER_DIRECT "CONNECT www.google.bg:443 HTTP/1.1"
10.62.8.109 - - [19/Jan/2016:14:25:16 +0200] 200 0 TCP_MISS:HIER_DIRECT "CONNECT ssl.gstatic.com:443 HTTP/1.1"
10.62.1.109 - - [19/Jan/2016:14:25:16 +0200] 200 0 TCP_MISS:HIER_DIRECT "CONNECT www.google.bg:443 HTTP/1.1"
10.62.1.109 - - [19/Jan/2016:14:25:16 +0200] 200 0 TCP_MISS:HIER_DIRECT "CONNECT www.google.bg:443 HTTP/1.1"
10.62.1.109 - - [19/Jan/2016:14:25:16 +0200] 200 0 TCP_MISS:HIER_DIRECT "CONNECT www.google.bg:443 HTTP/1.1"
```

What could be the reason for the crashes? I've checked the system resources nothing unusual I think.

Comment: "Laggy" and "crashes" arent the same thing.

Comment: connection becomes laggy minutes before the server stops resolving.I just noticed that.

Comment: First become laggy,very laggy then stops opening any websites total.I've never managed to find the solution of this problem so i retired the server and changed it with fw with integrated proxy.